# How do I detect scroll event in Gmail interface?

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, gmail

I'm trying to understand how to detect the scroll even in Gmail, (they use an iframe to contain the main content/interface and then use JS to create their scroll bar).

I'm using jQuery, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it...

#### Update

I found the element that I need to attach the scroll event to, if anyone cares:

`$canvas_frame.contents().find(".ar4 .Tm.aeJ")`

Where `$canvas_frame` is the `iframe` with the id of `#canvas_frame`, this is very particular to Gmail.

Comment: I tried getting the iframe contents and attaching a scroll event to any of the main elements there. I tried attaching a scroll event listener (jQuery) to the main window, and document. The reason that I ask, and there might be another trick to it, is that I know Rapportive embeds a plugin into the Gmail interface, and it changes its position (from relative to absolute) depending on the scroll position, to create a "scroll follow" effect).

Comment: I have found the right element to attach the scroll event to, it was sort of a hide and seek game in the DOM.

Comment: I know it's a bit old, but could you place the element needed as an answer and accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The **Same Origin Policy** prevents you from seeing whats going on in an Iframe that is not served from the same domain as the host page.

Comment: Perhaps, so is there another way to detect the scroll event?

Comment: The script i'm using is a Google Chrome extension, which should make it safe from the same origin rule, to clarify.